# How to Extract the Information from XML Soap Response?

Tags: python, xml, soap

We have a requirement to get the data from a SOAP XML Response.
Below is the associated XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetResultResponse xmlns="http://www.relatics.com/">
            <GetResultResult>
                <Report ReportName="RFC" GeneratedOn="2022-12-22" EnvironmentID="XXXX" EnvironmentName="Systematic Assurance – an XXX Solution" EnvironmentURL="https://XXXX.relaticsonline.com/" WorkspaceID="XXXXX" WorkspaceName="P - ADL Program Management - XXX" TargetDevice="Pc" ReportField="" xmlns="">
                    <Change_module>
                        <applied_individual_change_request Change_Request="TestKZIreport" RFC_GUID="XXXXX">
                            <code RFC_Code="VtW-0101" />
                            <progress RFC_Progress="agreed" />
                            <applied_individual_project_organisation Organisation="XXXX" />
                            <applied__individual_discipline Discipline="Highways" />
                            <specification Specification="Context of Documents">
                                <code Specification_Code="1.1.1a" />
                            </specification>
                            <applied_individual_workpackage Workpackage="Enabling work">
                                <code Workpackage_Code="WP-01" />
                            </applied_individual_workpackage>
                            <physical_object Physical_Object="Train Station">
                                <code Physical_Object_Code="TFO-0001" />
                            </physical_object>
                            <person approver="XXX" />
                            <applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification Consequence_Value="10 days">
                                <applied_conceptual_change_consequence_aspect Consequence_Aspect="Schedule" />
                            </applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification>
                            <document Document_Name="WI 300 Design.pdf">
                                <code Document_Code="DOC-0002" />
                            </document>
                            <answer_status BR_Status="no" />
                            <applied_individual_business_rule Business_Rule="Change Review compliance">
                                <code BR_Code="BR-006" />
                            </applied_individual_business_rule>
                            <applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification Consequence_Value="XXX">
                                <applied_conceptual_change_consequence_aspect Consequence_Aspect="Finance" />
                            </applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification>
                        </applied_individual_change_request>
                    </Change_module>
                </Report>
            </GetResultResult>
        </GetResultResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i need all the tag values after Change_module.i tried some online help in Stack overflow but  it didn't work.

I never worked with XML documents before and here is the sample code i
tried from Stack Overflow.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tree = ET.parse("Relatics_XML.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag)
print(root.attrib)

namespaces = {"soap": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/",
              "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
              "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/",
              'a': 'http://www.relatics.com/',}



names = tree.findall('./soap:Body''/a:GetResultResponse''/a:GetResultResult', namespaces)
print(names)

for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

i tried different methods like find and findall and also inside the method i try to pass different values but all its printing is null.
I'm not sure how to get the values out of tags.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that. StackOverflow is not a coding service, where you ask people to code for you.

Comment: @user56700 Thanks for the comment. I elaborated it now and please let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` make life easier.

documentation in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects)

It can parsing tag attribute or innerText.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetResultResponse xmlns="http://www.relatics.com/">
            <GetResultResult>
                <Report ReportName="RFC" GeneratedOn="2022-12-22" EnvironmentID="XXXX" EnvironmentName="Systematic Assurance – an XXX Solution" EnvironmentURL="https://XXXX.relaticsonline.com/" WorkspaceID="XXXXX" WorkspaceName="P - ADL Program Management - XXX" TargetDevice="Pc" ReportField=""
                    xmlns="">
                    <Change_module>
                        <applied_individual_change_request Change_Request="TestKZIreport" RFC_GUID="XXXXX">
                            <code RFC_Code="VtW-0101" />
                            <progress RFC_Progress="agreed" />
                            <applied_individual_project_organisation Organisation="XXXX" />
                            <applied__individual_discipline Discipline="Highways" />
                            <specification Specification="Context of Documents">
                                <code Specification_Code="1.1.1a" />
                            </specification>
                            <applied_individual_workpackage Workpackage="Enabling work">
                                <code Workpackage_Code="WP-01" />
                            </applied_individual_workpackage>
                            <physical_object Physical_Object="Train Station">
                                <code Physical_Object_Code="TFO-0001" />
                            </physical_object>
                            <person approver="XXX" />
                            <applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification Consequence_Value="10 days">
                                <applied_conceptual_change_consequence_aspect Consequence_Aspect="Schedule" />
                            </applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification>
                            <document Document_Name="WI 300 Design.pdf">
                                <code Document_Code="DOC-0002" />
                            </document>
                            <answer_status BR_Status="no" />
                            <applied_individual_business_rule Business_Rule="Change Review compliance">
                                <code BR_Code="BR-006" />
                            </applied_individual_business_rule>
                            <applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification Consequence_Value="XXX">
                                <applied_conceptual_change_consequence_aspect Consequence_Aspect="Finance" />
                            </applied_individual_change_consequence_qualification>
                        </applied_individual_change_request>
                    </Change_module>
                </Report>
            </GetResultResult>
        </GetResultResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

print("RFC_Code: " + str(root.find(".//code[@RFC_Code]").attrib))
print("RFC_Progress: " + str(root.find(".//progress[@RFC_Progress]").attrib))
print("specification: " + str(root.find(".//specification[@Specification]").attrib))
print("Specification_Code: " + str(root.find(".//code[@Specification_Code]").attrib))
print("Workpackage_Code: " + str(root.find(".//code[@Workpackage_Code]").attrib))
print("Document_Code: " + str(root.find(".//code[@Document_Code]").attrib))
```

Result

```
$ python get-data.py
RFC_Code: {'RFC_Code': 'VtW-0101'}
RFC_Progress: {'RFC_Progress': 'agreed'}
specification: {'Specification': 'Context of Documents'}
Specification_Code: {'Specification_Code': '1.1.1a'}
Workpackage_Code: {'Workpackage_Code': 'WP-01'}
Document_Code: {'Document_Code': 'DOC-0002'}
```

If you using xml file open, using this code

```
with open('data.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    root = ET.parse(xml_file)
```